# How to make a HTTP request to a REST service in PHP?

Tags: php, http, curl, fsockopen

I was wondering if anyone could help me understand how I would go about getting the JSON back using this information? Should I use cURL or fsockopen?

```
GET /market/10000002/orders/buy/?type=https://api-sisi.testeveonline.com/types/683/ HTTP/1.1
Host: https://api-sisi.testeveonline.com
```

> Authorization: Bearer jKVB8oaN9qboU5kQG4sWSoWxzSUaFkQaUyeisy8jWU3apRfYSgYsKpZGNbLh41xXEzuy-NDBX1FohEdEadaukQ2
>   Accept: application/vnd.ccp.eve.MarketOrderCollection-v1+json

I have tried doing this, but I have no clue whether or not this is a feasible way of doing it?

```
$fp = fsockopen("api.eveonline.com", 80, $errno, $errstr, 30);
if (!$fp) {
echo "$errstr ($errno)<br />\n";
} else {
$out = "GET /market/10000002/orders/buy/?    type=https://api.eveonline.com/types/683/ HTTP/1.1\r\n";
$out .= "Host: https://api.eveonline.com\r\n";
$out .= "Authorization: Bearer ".auth."\r\n\r\n";
$out .= "Accept: application/vnd.ccp.eve.MarketOrderCollection-v1+json\r\n\r\n";
fwrite($fp, $out);
while (!feof($fp)) {
    echo fgets($fp, 128);
}
fclose($fp);
}
```

Thanks

EDIT 1:

```
$opts = array('http' =>
  array(
    'method'  => 'GET',
    'header'  => "Host: https://api.eveonline.com\r\n".
    "Authorization: Bearer ".auth."\r\n".
    "Accept: application/vnd.ccp.eve.MarketOrderCollection-v1+json\r\n"
  )
);

$context  = stream_context_create($opts);
$url = 'https://api.eveonline.com/';
$result = file_get_contents($url, false, $context);
```

This was my next attempt that I am still working on.

Comment: You should use cURL. There're plenty of tutorials to find out how, incl. PHP manual.

Comment: I quite like [Pest](https://github.com/educoder/pest) for accessing REST APIs.

Comment: Thanks halfer, I am trying file_get_contents at the moment as suggested, but if I can't get to grips with that I will get Pest a go.

Answer (score 1):

fsockopen is really not a good option for HTTP requests as you have to take care of everything yourself (such as compression, chunking, etc.). [cURL](http://php.net/manual/en/book.curl.php) sure is an option, but my favourite is just [`file_get_contents`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.file-get-contents.php). You need to have `allow_url_fopen` set to `On` in the config, but that's not really a security risk and the function itself is very capable.

Comment: I'm working on it at the moment, having a few problems, but seem to be slowly getting there. Unsure where to put all of the text after the GET. Will edit main post shortly

Comment: Added to main post, unsure if I am doing this properly.

Comment: You should be able to just append it to the URL: `file_get_contents('http://example.com/some/path/?a=b&c=d', false, $context)`